# Problems with getting data using the LABEL functionality in Pine on the Tradingview platform

Tags: pine-script

I am using a function that is part of the `Pinescript` on `Tradingview.` The function determines the Pivot Points of a Series. I am using it to `collect Pivot Points for the RSI.`

The function works; however, what I would like to do is to generate a Series that ONLY has either the `Pivot Points` generated `or a zero` (**see Picture #1** below). If the numbers fetched (for the Pivot Points) are correct, then I should be able to plot them on the Chart - and - they would wind up under the Yellow Labels (**see Picture #2** below)

**BACKGROUND**

To do this, I am working with `label.get_text()` as seen here: [https://kodify.net/tradingview/labels/get-text/[1]](https://kodify.net/tradingview/labels/get-text/%5B1%5D)

When doing so, I had the following problems:

1. I could not verify whether or not the data was assigned properly
2. I needed the value to be converted to a float. When doing something like `float( label.get_text()),` I got an error

> line 270: Cannot call 'float' with arguments (series[string]);
> available overloads: float(const float) => const float; float(input
> float) => input float; float(float) => float; float(series[float]) =>
> series[float];

**QUESTIONS**

1. How can one convert a string to a float in Pine
2. I wanted to gather a series of Pivot Points. Ideally, there would be one series for the HIGHEST points and another series for the LOWEST points.

Any help, hints or advice would be most greatly appreciated

TIA

**PICTURE NO 1**
[image: PICTURE #1]

**PICTURE NO 2**
[image: PICTURE #2]

**FUNCTION : create_pivot_points**

```
create_pivot_points(src, len, isHigh, _style, _yloc, _color, _textcolor, _offset, _plot_data) =>
    
    [ ... snip ...]
    
    pivot_src_len = len

    p = nz(src[pivot_src_len])
    
    isFound = true
    for i = 0 to len - 1
        if isHigh and src[i] > p
            isFound := false

        if not isHigh and src[i] < p
            isFound := false

    for i = len + 1 to 2 * len
        if isHigh and src[i] >= p
            isFound := false

        if not isHigh and src[i] <= p
            isFound := false

    if isFound
        if isHigh // printing the highest high pivots
        
        NOTE: I am using the command below label.XXXX to try to get information about the label

            pivotPointHighLabel = label.new(bar_index[pivot_src_len], int(p) + 10 , tostring(truncate(p,2)), style=_style, yloc=_yloc, color=noneColor, textcolor=noneColor)

            high_kdcLabel_XCoords := label.get_x( pivotPointHighLabel )
            high_kdcLabel_YCoords := label.get_y( pivotPointHighLabel )
            high_kdcLabel_Data    := float( label.get_text( pivotPointHighLabel ) ) <---- receiving error message here when attempting to change value from a STRING to a FLOAT
            high_kdcLabel_Bool    := high_kdcLabel_Data == 0.0 ? false : true
            
            if _plot_data //make the labels visible
                label.set_color(pivotPointHighLabel, _color)
                label.set_textcolor(pivotPointHighLabel, _textcolor)
            
        else    // printing the lowest low pivots (assume isLow has been activated)

    [ ... snip ...]
    
    // returning information below to calling code
    [high_kdcLabel_XCoords, high_kdcLabel_YCoords, high_kdcLabel_Data, high_kdcLabel_Bool, low_kdcLabel_XCoords, low_kdcLabel_YCoords, low_kdcLabel_Data, low_kdcLabel_Bool]
```

**MAIN CODE:**

```
[ ... snip ...]
if plotUpperPivotPoint
    [hin_x_coords, hin_y_coords, hin_label_data, hin_bool_data, lin_x_coords, lin_y_coords, lin_label_data, lin_bool_data] = 
            pivothl(osc, len, true , label.style_labeldown, yloc.price, color.yellow, color.black, 0, plotUpperPivotPoint)
    high_x_coords    := hin_x_coords
    high_y_coords    := hin_y_coords
    high_label_data  := hin_label_data
    high_bool_data   := hin_bool_data
    
    f_print( tostring(high_label_data) )
    

// attempting to test any data retrieved to see if it will work with the labels.
// if the list of Upper Limits (Pivots) is correct, the BLUE heart-beat spikes on the picture below
// should match right under the yellow labels
testme = high_label_data == 0 ? 0 : 70
plot( testme,  offset=-lbR, color=color.blue )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to figure things out from your snippet, but given a function like `pivothigh()` with returns the pivot's value when one is found and `na` otherwise, you can use code like this:

```
//@version=4
study("", "", true)
i_legs = input(4)
// When a non `na` value is returned, use zero, otherwise use the value.
pHi = nz(pivothigh(i_legs, i_legs))
plot(pHi)
```

The code builds the series as pivots are detected, which is `i_legs` after the actual pivot, contrary to how most pivot indicators plot pivots, i.e., by offsetting them `i_legs` bars in the past:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there a way I would like to try this out - but - how can one print the values of the series (have not heard of a debugger being associated with Pinescript as of yet)?

Comment: See the Pine User Manual on [Debugging](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/Debugging.html).